Price rules are not being applied to cart in shopify line item
I currently have added a price rule to shopify via the post method.
const title = body.get("title");

const price_rule = new admin.rest.resources.PriceRule({session: session});
price_rule.title = title;
price_rule.value_type = "fixed_amount";
price_rule.value = "-10";
price_rule.customer_selection = "all";
price_rule.target_type ="line_item";
price_rule.target_selection = "entitled";
price_rule.allocation_method = "each";
price_rule.starts_at = "2018-03-22T00:00:00-00:00";
price_rule.entitled_product_ids = [
  6952008155224
];

price_rule.prerequisite_quantity_range = {
  "greater_than_or_equal_to": 2,
}

price_rule.allocation_limit = 3;

await price_rule.save({
  update: true,
});

My expectation is that when I add the product 6952008155224 with greater or equal to quantity 2.  That each item would deduct 10.
Meaning if product is 30 it would -10 and give each one at 20.
However I don't see anything in the cart or the checkout regarding the discount.
The post went in successful but it's not executing.
Any idea if i'm missing something?

Shopify's price rules don't automatically apply to the cart or checkout without being explicitly associated with discount codes. Price rules by themselves define the logic for discounts, but they need to be tied to discount codes for them to take effect.
So, you'll need to create a discount code associated with the price rule that you created.
const discount_code = new admin.rest.resources.DiscountCode({session: session});
discount_code.code = "DISCOUNT10";
discount_code.price_rule_id = price_rule.id;

await discount_code.save();

For the automatic discounts, Shopify's REST API doesn't directly allow for automatic discounts through price rules. You'd need to configure automatic discounts via Shopify Admin instead.

As a side note, by looking at your codes, it seems like the discount type is Buy X Get Y, but I'm not sure if this price rule can work. You may need to define prerequisite_product_ids as well.
Since your expectation is to get -$10 off for the 6952008155224 products when you added this product with greater or equal to quantity 2, you might set prerequisite_product_ids as same as entitled_product_ids like below.
price_rule.prerequisite_product_ids = [
  6952008155224
];
price_rule.entitled_product_ids = [
  6952008155224
];

